# how to transform bitmap texture to the original image in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, image-processing, bitmap, image-rotation

I am currently working on a project in opengl and I am displaying a texture of a bitmap on a rotating polygon, like this :

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureId);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-BOX_SIZE / 2, -BOX_SIZE / 2, BOX_SIZE / 2);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(BOX_SIZE / 2, -BOX_SIZE / 2, BOX_SIZE / 2);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(BOX_SIZE / 2, BOX_SIZE / 2, BOX_SIZE / 2);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-BOX_SIZE / 2, BOX_SIZE / 2, BOX_SIZE / 2);

glEnd();
```

and I can stop the rotation so the image is not facing directly to the camera.
Now, what I need to do is to transform the side looking version of the image to the original one using opengl.
I could not find the right method to do so.
the rotate is done using simple flutTimerFunc and glRotatef :

```
glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0);
```

the update function :

```
void update(int value) {
    if (_flag)
    {
        _angle += 1.0f;
        if (_angle > 360) {
            _angle -= 360;
        }
        glutPostRedisplay();
        glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0);
    }

}
```

and in scene draw I have this line :

```
glRotatef(-_angle, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What do you mean with original image and side looking image? How many images do you have and what did you change in the original image?

Comment: the original image is a bitmap image of a tree for example. and the side looking image is the I view the image from the side. I have 1 image of the object and I didnt change anything in the original image. thanks for the response.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do any rotation. Post more so we can see how is the rotation done and how is it stopped.

Comment: I edited the post, thanks for the response.